# is praying very late a sin

Tags: sin, salat-qada

I remember yesterday I was going back home with my parents from france it was really far to get home and we arrived home at 12:06am and I prayed isha and this very late time and also I thought allah will punish me if I pray late

Comment: kind of but actually no

Comment: @Goodmuslim Nope It's not a sin at all to pray late, though It shouldn't be like 5 minutes from qaza.

Comment: @Syed Mohammad Sannan ok thanks